# Get metadata for a column with google Sheets API

Tags: google-api, python-3.7, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I have a Google spreadsheet that I am connecting to and interacting with using the `google-python-api-client` package. Following [this description on metadata search](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.developerMetadata/search), and the links in it for the request body, I have written a function to get metadata for a range:

```
def get_metadata_by_range(range_: Union[dict, str]) -> dict:
    if isinstance(range_, str):
        print("String range: ", range_)
        request_body = {"dataFilters": \
                            {"a1Range": range_}}
    elif isinstance(range_, dict):
        print("Dict range: ", range_)
        request_body = {"dataFilters": \
                            [{"gridRange": range_}]}
    else:
        return None
    request = service.spreadsheets().developerMetadata().\
            search(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, body=request_body)
    return request.execute()
```

Calling this with a range, either A1 notation or a `gridRange` will cause an error to occur though. For example, calling it with this line `get_metadata_by_range("Metadata!A:A")` will cause the following traceback.

```
String range:  Metadata!A:A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "oqc_server/fab/gapc.py", line 82, in <module>
    get_metadata_by_range("Metadata!A:A")
  File "oqc_server/fab/gapc.py", line 69, in get_metadata_by_range
    return request.execute()
  File "/media/kajsa/Storage/Projects/oqc_server/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/kajsa/Storage/Projects/oqc_server/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 856, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 500 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1RhheCsI3kHrm8yK2Yio2kAOU4VOzYdz-eK0vjiMY7co/developerMetadata:search?alt=json returned "Internal error encountered."
```

Any ideas on what is causing this and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

- You want to search and retrieve the developer metadata from the range using the method of Method: spreadsheets.developerMetadata.search of Sheets API.
- You want to achieve this using google-api-python-client with python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Spreadsheet with Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- When you want to search the developer metadata with the range, please set the gridrange to `dataFilters[].developerMetadataLookup.metadataLocation.dimensionRange`.

  - When the range is set to `dataFilters[].a1Range` and `dataFilters[].gridRange`, I could confirm that the same error occurs.

#### Sample script:

The sample script for retrieving the developer metadata from the range is as follows. Before you use this, please set the variables of `spreadsheet_id` and `sheet_id`.

```
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
spreadsheet_id = '###'  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheet_id = ###  # Please set the sheet ID.

search_developer_metadata_request_body = {
    "dataFilters": [
        {
            "developerMetadataLookup": {
                "metadataLocation": {
                    "dimensionRange": {
                        "sheetId": sheet_id,
                        "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                        "startIndex": 0,
                        "endIndex": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

request = service.spreadsheets().developerMetadata().search(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=search_developer_metadata_request_body)
response = request.execute()
print(response)
```

- Above script retrieves the developer metadata from the column "A" of `sheet_id`.

#### Note:

- Please modify above script for your actual script.
- In the current stage, the Developer Metadata can be added to the Spreadsheet, each sheet in the Spreadsheet and row and column. Please be careful this. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/metadata)

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.developerMetadata.search](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.developerMetadata/search)
- [Adding Developer Metadata](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/metadata)- [DeveloperMetadataLookup](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DataFilter#DeveloperMetadataLookup)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: I ended up doing a workaround like this, however that requires transforming a `gridRange` into a `dimensionRange` or even worse, an `a1Range` into a `dimenstionRange`. I think it is a good workaround but hopefully they will solve the underlying issue so that you can use regular ranges in the future.

Comment: @Kajsa Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my answer was not the direction you expect.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with developerMetadata related to a1Range objects being passed as filters.

## Edit

I've checked the bug again and a fix has been implemented.

Comment: Have you tried adding metadata to other ranges as well? Using this I get all the metadata for the whole document, not just the range I wanted.

Comment: Also, just remembered that this page states that you can only use one filter type.
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DataFilter
Which is probably making the first item, which is an all inclusive lookup, the one that is actually used. And that would explain why I get all the data from the whole document.

Comment: @Kajsa yes, sorry, you are correct. I have just tested it and it seems to be a bug.

Comment: I also get the same error if I try using the `gridRange` option.